# Neo4j: search in children too

Tags: search, neo4j, cypher

I have a simple parent/child graph in neo4j. I would like search the parents (and its children) with a property value in parent node or in child node. 
A parent can have (or not) a list of children

I tried this query

```
MATCH (p:Parent) 
WHERE p.lastName =~ "(?i).*.*" 
RETURN p AS parent, [] as children 
UNION 
MATCH (p:Parent) - [:REL] -> (c:Child) 
WHERE p.lastName =~ "(?i).*1234.*" OR c.name =~ "(?i).*.*"  
RETURN p AS parent, c AS collect(children)
```

but it's not perfect: this query return not distinct result.

Do you know a better query to have a list of parents and its children with property value in parent node or child node.

The logic should be:

```
if (p.lastName == x) OR (p.children.name == x)
    return p
```

**UPDATE**

I give you more elements:

Example:

```
(p1:Parent { lastName: "AAA" }) no children

(p2:Parent { lastName: "BBB" }) 2 children 
    (c1:Child { name: "CCC" })
    (c2:Child { name: "DDD"})
```

If I execute this query

```
MATCH (p:Parent)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:REL]->(c:Child)
WHERE p.lastName CONTAINS 'DDD' OR c.name CONTAINS 'DDD'
RETURN p AS parent, collect(c) AS children;
```

the result is p1, p2 with c2. I would like only p2 with c2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I assume you have typos in a couple of your regular expressions, and that they should all actually be `"(?i).*1234.*`".*

[UPDATED TWICE]

In Cypher, the `UNION` clause *additively* combines result rows, which explains why you did not get distinct results.

This query might be closer to what you want:

```
MATCH (p1:Parent)
WHERE p1.lastName CONTAINS 'DDD'
OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[:REL]->(c1:Child)
WITH COLLECT({parent: p1, child: c1}) AS x
OPTIONAL MATCH (p2:Parent)-[:REL]->(c2:Child)
WHERE c2.name CONTAINS 'DDD' AND NOT(p2.lastName CONTAINS 'DDD')
WITH x + (CASE WHEN p2 IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT({parent: p2, child: c2}) END) AS y
UNWIND y AS z
RETURN z.parent AS parent, COLLECT(z.child) AS children;
```

It first collects all `Parent` nodes having the desired `lastName`, along with their `Child` nodes, if any. It then appends to that collection all `Parent/Child` nodes pairs where the parent does NOT have the appropriate `lastName` but the child does have the desired `name`. Finally, it returns each distinct `Parent` node along with its `Child` nodes.

Comment: Your query is better but not perfect: your query always returns all parent node even if the where clause is not verified for the partent

Comment: It's like my query. The only difference is contains instead of =~

Comment: The last `WHERE` clause is different.

Comment: The new one is better but the first match returns all  parents without children and the second one the parents with children. So, the results are not distinct

Comment: Please state exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to search parent node with a given property value or parent node with children with a given property value. The parent node returned must contains the list of children (empty if he doesn't have children)

Comment: Don't you also have a requirement for "distinct" answers? What do you mean by "distinct"?

Comment: If I'm looking for all parents (CONTAINS "") your query returns p1, p2 (with no children), p2 (with children). I would like p1, p2 (with children)

Comment: do you have any idea?